# Wicket application running in tomcat 7 does not allow to set timeout session longer than 30 minutes

Tags: java, tomcat7, wicket, wicket-6

I'm running a wicket application in tomcat 7 and was trying to set timeout to 60 minutes.

As described in tomcat documentation I configured web.xml setting it this
way

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

To test this was working OK I tried 1st with 5 minutes and everything worked as expected.

But when I set in in 60 minutes the session expired at 30, to be fair something like 35 that was my test.

I've looked in the web, and although some people mentioned this problem no solution or bug comment was provided.

For now just trying to detect if this is a wicket problem or a tomcat7 problem, takes very long to test :-).

Has anyone faced a similar problem

Thanks very much

tonio

Comment: Have you looked into Tomcat 7 config? maxInactiveInterval seems to be default set to 30. Here is the link: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html

Comment: Just put your system time 29 mins ahead :p

Comment: Hi Mihir (thanks for your answer),  wasn't aware of maxInactiveInterval,  configured application context using a Manager with maxInactiveInterval set to 1hour (3600 secs.) but still failing

Answer (score 1):

Wicket doesn't read/write the session timeout anywhere, so it is not to blame. You can try with simple application that has just a Servlet to verify.

The Servlet API provides a way to set this setting with `http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)`

Comment: Just trying to avoid constructing some configuration infrastructure to be able to customize session-timeout at runtime and see if it can be done using standard tomcat things, anyway I'll try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is what marting-g described

In my case:

1. Create/Configure an HttpSessionListener
2. Configure sessionCreated() method to set the maxInactiveInterval taken from a properties file.

Works perfectly ok
thanks all